# Dynamic Date Ranges in Chart.js from SQL

Tags: mysql, chart.js

Hi There I spent an afternoon getting my sql to dynamically populate the date ranges for a chart.js graph and decided to share the code to help anyone in the future. 
The code that i have written will take the date range you have inputted and check the time between the two dates then depending on the time between the two dates will give you a different time span for your graph.

Here is the full query

```
 SELECT  
 name AS "Company"
 IF( DATEDIFF( FROM_UNIXTIME( [end_date], '%Y-%m-%d' ), FROM_UNIXTIME( 
 [start_date], '%Y-%m-%d' )) <= 8, 
 DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME( insert_date, '%Y-%m-%d' ), '%a %D %M'),
 IF( DATEDIFF( FROM_UNIXTIME( [end_date], '%Y-%m-%d' ), FROM_UNIXTIME( 
 [start_date], '%Y-%m-%d' )) BETWEEN 8 AND 62, 
 CONCAT("WC - ", DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(FROM_UNIXTIME( insert_date, 
 '%Y' ), 1), INTERVAL WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME( insert_date, '%Y-%m-%d' )) 
 WEEK), "%d %M %Y")), 
 IF( DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME( [end_date], '%Y-%m-%d' ), FROM_UNIXTIME( 
 [start_date], '%Y-%m-%d' )) > 62, 
 CONCAT(MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME( insert_date, '%Y-%m-%d' 
 )), '%m'))," ",FROM_UNIXTIME( insert_date, '%Y' )),''))) AS labels ,
 CONCAT(
 "Generated (",COUNT( insert_date ),")"
 ) AS toolTip

 FROM (inserted_cases) 
 WHERE insert_date BETWEEN [start_date] AND [end_date]
 GROUP BY labels
```

Now the bit that does all the calculations for you is here and will work for quite a few other things as well but im suggesting it for chart.js as i have tested it on here.

```
 IF( DATEDIFF( FROM_UNIXTIME( [end_date], '%Y-%m-%d' ), FROM_UNIXTIME( 
     [start_date], '%Y-%m-%d' )) <= 8, 
       DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME( insert_date, '%Y-%m-%d' ), '%a %D %M'),
 IF( DATEDIFF( FROM_UNIXTIME( [end_date], '%Y-%m-%d' ), FROM_UNIXTIME( 
     [start_date], '%Y-%m-%d' )) BETWEEN 8 AND 62, 
       CONCAT("WC - ", DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(FROM_UNIXTIME( 
       insert_date, '%Y' ), 1), INTERVAL WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME( 
       insert_date, '%Y-%m-%d' )) WEEK), "%d %M %Y")), 
 IF( DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME( [end_date], '%Y-%m-%d' ), FROM_UNIXTIME( 
     [start_date], '%Y-%m-%d' )) > 62, 
       CONCAT(MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME( insert_date, '%Y- 
       %m-%d' )), '%m'))," ",FROM_UNIXTIME( insert_date, '%Y' )),''))) AS 
       labels ,
```

I hope this can help to save so time in the future. also if you know of a better way im always open to suggestion and learning new things. happy coding guys. :)